# Does a function gets stack frame when called using a function pointer in C?

Tags: c, function

If a function pointer points to a function inside the code section of the memory , does that function gets its own stack frame when called using the function pointer.

Comment: I am under the impression that you think there is a difference in calling a function in C by its name vs by a function pointer. In reality once C is compiled into machine code all function calls end up being the `call` instruction, which takes the address of the first instruction of a function as an operand (or a register which contains this address). Effectively, every time you call a function you are using its address (the language just hides it from you).

Comment: In the machine code, calling a function from a function pointer is no different than calling it directly.

Comment: Note: the C99 standard contains 0 mentions of the word `stack` and another 0 for the word `frame`. Technically you can have an implementation that does not use stack frames. So "same as an ordinary function call" with the note that this can be yes or no depending on the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr - Yes, no different than when the function is called directly.

---

If we have code like:

```
void func() {
}

typedef void (*func_ptr)();

int main() {
    func_ptr ptr = func;
    ptr();
}
```

in assembly, the call to `ptr()` will [become](https://godbolt.org/z/Wd4T7Mjjd) something like:

```
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], OFFSET FLAT:func
mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
call    rdx
```

you can see that `call rdx` is equivalent to `call func` (because `rdx == func`). A stack frame is defined by both the information pushed to the stack by the `call` in assembly, and by the information pushed by the function itself in its prologue - both of which are equivalent when called directly (`call func`) or indirectly with a function pointer (`call rdx`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For a function *f* and a function pointer *fp* which points to *f*, the only difference between the function call *f*() and *fp*() is that there is an extra (implicit) pointer indirection step before the latter call.